# How to add class for body tag

Tags: css, tags

I add a forbody class and put it in the body part of the css. Same for the code in the css. But It doesn't work.

**in code**

```
<body class="forbody">


</body>
```

**in css**

```
body .forbody {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  height:1150px;
  }
```

Comment: remove the body word in css

Comment: I removed the body and only leave it as .forbody in the css and it worked. @airi

Comment: CSS should be `body.forbody` (no space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you use class for forbody you no need to put body infront, used the class name

```
<body class="forbody"> - html

.forbody {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  height:1150px;
}
```

or in certain cases you can also do like this if do not want external css or used class :

```
<body style="padding:0px;margin:0;max-width:100px;height:1150px;">
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the space between `body` and `.forbody` in the CSS. A space designates another element further down the tree. That is, `body .forbody` (with a space) will target *children of a body element*, with the class "forbody". Without the space, `body.forbody` will target body elements themselves, when they have the class "forbody".

Alternatively, if the class "forbody" will only be used for the body - or in other words, you do not need to discern between `body.forbody` and `p.forbody` for example - you can simply omit the "body" part altogether in the selector, leaving `.forbody { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need the `body` part. The CSS should look like this:

```
.forbody {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  height:1150px;
}
```

Hope this helps!